# SignalR not working Protocol error: Unknown transport

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, knockout.js, signalr

I am trying to refer this article on SignalR and Knockout.js but something isn't working. I am referring this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/322154/ASP-NET-MVC-SIngalR-and-Knockout-based-Real-time-U

I downloaded the code and setup to run on my SQL server but I just can't get it to work. Attached is the error that I am getting

[image]

Can anybody let me know what the problem can be?

Answer (score 2):

I found that I was referencing the old version of SignalR. If anybody downloads the code from that link and updates using Nuget make sure you reference SignalR script with 0.5 version